# Generated pdf file save inside the project folder

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

i want to save the generated pdf file inside my project folder ,
    using this code . I have generated it successfully and want to save
    it in my project folder , where the jsp file exist ,Below is my code

```
 <%@ page import="java.servlet.*,
        javax.servlet.http.*,
        java.io.*,
        java.util.*,
        com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*,
        com.itextpdf.text.*,java.sql.*" %><%

response.setContentType("application/pdf"); Document document = new
Document(); try{
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer);
    document.open();


    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.addCell("1");
    table.addCell("2");
    table.addCell("3");
    table.addCell("4");
    table.addCell("5");
    table.addCell("6");       


    document.add(table);       
    document.close();

    DataOutput dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
    {
        dataOutput.writeByte(bytes[i]);
    }
    }catch(DocumentException e){
    e.printStackTrace(); }

  %>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: you forgot to add a question.

Comment: and also, it would help if we know Why?

Comment: What is the Qs? People will not reply back, if you do not provide a meaning ful Qs .

Comment: Question: i want to save the generated pdf file in my current directory . where my jsp file exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use getServletContext().getRealPath(..)